# Regarding on the sum but not the alphba

Tags: google-chrome

I've a problem,

```
     A       B
1 ARC 245
2 CAB 234
3 ABS 345
```

If I only want to sum up the numbers in the cell A 1,A 3 together but not the alpha, how do I go about it?

Answer (score 1):

Without using VBA, here are two *array formulas* you could use. For these to work, you need to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. You should see curly braces appear around the formula if you've done it correctly.

This first one is a little simpler, but your data *must* be in the same format it is now, where the last three characters are the numbers you wish to sum:

```
=SUM(NUMBERVALUE(RIGHT(A1:A3,LEN(A1:A3)-4)))
```

[image]

This grabs the right most three characters between A1:A3, converts them to a number and adds them together.

This formula is a little more complicated but will work with any length numbers:

```
=SUM(NUMBERVALUE(RIGHT(A1:A3,LEN(A1:A3) - MIN(FIND({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},A1:A3&"0123456789")) +1)))
```

[image]

This finds the first instance of a number, then trims to that instead of assuming to only use 3 characters.

If your sample data is *not* representative of your actual data (EG. Letters could appear after the numbers) these formulas will not work, and you should potentially look to creating a UDF or other VBA solution.